# In iOS11, how to keep a background task running past 10 min?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, background-process, ios11

My question involves keeping an app that monitors user interactions in the background, for example time spent in one or the app. The issue arises when you can not have a background process run for more than 10 min or violate Apple's sandbox restrictions. Since I am relatively new to the Apple API, and could not find a direct answer that didn't involve location services or VOIP (which are both interesting options, but my application will not be able to use either viably), I come to ask for options in which I can understand when another app opens, when it closes, when it fetches data, and when user holds phone in certain orientation (ie when people hold their phone at certain angles to read text and etc.) for certain amount of time.

The purpose of this analyzation is to predict an attention span for the user, so I need to be able to run in the background, as the user will not be using my app while it predicts attention span.

My thoughts on this are possibly accessing the system log, and somehow parse previous statements (I don't think sandbox will allow), but inevitably the iOS system will suspend my processes after some point unless I put a timer. There is also the option of having the system wake up my app via opportunistic fetching, but that won't be useful if I don't collect the data.

Keep in mind this is within IOS 11, so it is much more restrictive than previous iterations. I understand this may seem like a complex problem, but even a direction in which to head could be useful to me.

Comment: any analysis that targets the device / other apps, rather than your app is bound to be stopped by apple sooner or later :/

Comment: You can't do what you want to do.  Permitted iOS background execution modes are described in the iOS Application Programming Guide.  There is no option for indefinite background execution.  Misusing background modes such as audio or location will lead to rejection.

Answer (score 0):

This solution might work, (not recommended since it drains the battery quicker). 
Just update your current location, every 10 mins. It will reset the background thread timer.